# Create multipart geometry in geometry by expression

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I'm trying to create a multiline geometry looking like the lines in my screenshot. I've created it by duplicating a line style 12 times on a point layer, rotating it by +30 degrees.

Isn't it possible using one expression? Like this (ERROR):

```
--first line
rotate(
    make_line(
        centroid($geometry), make_point(x(centroid($geometry)), 
        y(centroid($geometry))+1000))
, 0, centroid($geometry))
,
--second line
rotate(
    make_line(
        centroid($geometry), make_point(x(centroid($geometry)), 
        y(centroid($geometry))+1000))
, 30, centroid($geometry)),
,
--third line
rotate(
    make_line(
        centroid($geometry), make_point(x(centroid($geometry)), 
        y(centroid($geometry))+1000))
, 60, centroid($geometry))
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` together with `array_foreach()` for this purpose and then use `collect_geometries()` to turn the array of lines into a multiline geometry:

```
collect_geometries(array_foreach(generate_series(0,330,30), -- 330 instead of 360 to not draw the line at 0 and 360 twice
rotate(make_line(
centroid($geometry), make_point(x(centroid($geometry)), 
y(centroid($geometry))+1000))
,@element,centroid($geometry))))
```