# Function to draw lines based on starting point, angle and length

Tags: qgis, r, line, vector

I have used an R script to calculate the distance from a point within a polygon to the edge of the polygon at 1-degree increments. This has been saved as a CSV file. I am now wanting to create a shapefile of vector data to represent this information in QGIS. Is there a way to draw vectors of a given length, angle (0-360) and starting point using a function or script rather than drawing each line manually? For context this is the distance of a buoy in a lake to the lake edges.

[image]

The first 5 lines of the CSV are below:

| line.distance | thetas |
| --- | --- |
| 4669.310681 | 1 |
| 4644.783120 | 2 |
| 4630.030523 | 3 |
| 4614.497676 | 4 |
| 4621.2902638 | 5 |

@Spacedman your answer was what I needed. Could you help me with trying to correctly centre the line? when using the script I end up with the below image. The difficulty I'm having is correctly identifying the coordinates between lat and long for the R script and my QGIS project projection NZTM 2000 EPSG:2193.

[image]

Comment: There has to be x and y coordinates in the csv file aswell? This can get you started: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415157/create-multipart-geometry-in-geometry-by-expression

Answer (score 2):

Loads of ways of doing this. Easiest may be to compute the X and Y coords of the start and finish points in R and create a GeoPackage and load that into QGIS instead - use the `sf` package in R to do this. You can compute the X and Y coords given start coordinate, distance, and angle using trigonometry.

Or to do in QGIS from the CSV, create a virtual layer which creates a line geometry using trigonometry.

I loaded a test CSV into a layer using "Add Layer" "Delimited Text Layer" and got a layer with no geometry called `d`. This has two columns, `line.distance` and `thetas`. Then "Create Layer" "New Virtual Layer" and use some SQL like this:

```
select makeline(
 st_point(1234, 5678),
 st_point(
  1234+"line.distance"*sin(thetas*3.14/180),
  5678+"line.distance"*cos(thetas*3.14/180)
  )
) as geometry from d
```

Note the central point is coordinate (1234, 5678) in whatever coordinate system you are using, and the numbers appear twice here. The conversion from degrees to radians uses pi=3.14 as an approximation, maybe put in another couple of decimal places for pi. The resulting virtual layer should have line geometry and for my test data looks like this:

[image]

since it was created with increasing `line.distance` with `thetas` from north (`thetas=0`) going clockwise round.

You may also need to set a CRS on the layer to get it in the right place, my test data is in the ocean only a few km from (0,0) ("Null Island") in Web Mercator coordinates.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, thank you very much this worked well in QGIS. The only issue I am currently having is that I can't get the correct projection and centre point coordinate from my R script (long, lat) in this code (the 1234, 5678 is off centre to my project and vector shapefile for the lake outline). When I run it the line geometry is slightly of the centre of where the distances were created. Do you have any suggestions for how to get the correct CRS/projection?